# Block Producer vs Relay Node setup

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, token, cardano-db-sync, cardano-foundation

Can only Pool operators run Producer nodes? What is the difference between the producer and relay from a setup point and where to get the specifics for each on installing? Being new it's hard to know what is or is not possible because the documentation is often era specific. It's hard to know which documentation still applies and what docs are out dated. Some things are still correct regardless of era, but I'm struggling with the changes.

My goal is to learn how to do most everything (Best practices, Node creation, CLI interaction, Smart Contracts w/NFT and tokens, analysis etc ) accept I'm not planning on running a pool since it seems like there are so many pools that are not doing well for a number of different reasons. I figure it will be a struggle to get enough ADA staked to make it viable. I first want to mint my own NFTs. NFT-maker pro isn't working. I want to limit the fees by doing myself and am struggling with a full road map. If seen the sprout vids and they get me 3 steps forward but are missing certain details.

If nothing else getting a really good starting point would help.

James

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get started with Cardano, **setting up a stake pool can be a good start to learn the basics**. You will be able to explore the different cli commands as well as the fundamentals of the eUTX0 model.

Regarding my experience, I started by watching this official [Stake Pool course](https://cardano-foundation.gitbook.io/stake-pool-course/) by the Cardano Foundation. The information is not all up to date but the explanatory videos make it easy to understand the basics (UTXO transactions, payment keys, staking keys, KES keys ...). It's a good base to experiment a Stake Pool on the Testnet.

Once this course is finished, you can now go to the documentation ["How to build a Cardano Stake Pool" on CoinCashew](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node). This is the most complete How-To to learn how to properly install and configure your Stake Pool for the Mainnet. It also includes the routines to maintain and keep your Cardano nodes functional.

If after that you still have difficulties or questions, you can go to the [official Cardano forum](https://forum.cardano.org/c/staking-delegation/setup-a-stake-pool/158) to ask for help from the community.

Have fun and good luck!